# I want to add 14 days / 30 days from created date in firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How can I add 14 days / 30 days to createdAt firestore date/time field, I will create another field called expiresIn to store future date after adding 14 days / 30 days..

I am using `const timeStamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();` to create createdAt using cloud functions onCreate method.. then will run schedule job to subtract remaining days and finally mark as Expired (or False).. How can add days to existing createdAt field ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` without actually writing to the database. So if that if what you want, you'll have to create another Cloud Function (or branch in your existing one) to detect when the `createdAt`  gets written, and create your schedule based on that.

But when using Cloud Functions, the local server time is managed by Google, and is typically going to be quite close to the value of `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. Given your 14/30 day interval, I'd just start with `Date.now()` and then add the period to that.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the clarification. Do you have any past links where I can find how to use Period methods to add/compare days/time and update remaining days field in my document.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new date based on an existing date in the doc (Field type = Timestamp, field name = `existingDate`), you can use the following Cloud Function, which uses the [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) library:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const moment = require('moment');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.addFourteenDays = functions.firestore
    .document('testCollection/{docId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const existingDateTimestamp = snap.get("existingDate");
        const existingDate = existingDateTimestamp.toDate();

        const momentexistingDate = moment(existingDate);
        const momentFourteenDaysDate = momentexistingDate.add(14, 'days');

        return snap.ref.update({ fourteenDaysDate: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(momentFourteenDaysDate.toDate()) });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud, I will try this method, also will check out the moment documentation.

Comment: Hello @developer-rahul, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hi Renaud, Thanks your solution worked. But Also I want to run a daily corn job to cross check expiry date against current day to to mark once listing has expired (passed 14 or 30 days) using cloud function... also I want to update the remaining days field based on difference between expiry day and current day... these date formats are killing me when run the test on real could functions, needs to set up the firebase emulators